# ViewController occasionally miss in responder chain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i meet a very strange thing today: that my custom ViewController occasionally miss in responder chain

first i have a custom UIView, with a UIButton as its subview, then i set the target-action as usual:

```
[closeButton addTarget:self.controller action:@selector(closeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

of course, i implement the closeButtonPressed method in my custom UIViewController

in most time, it just worked fine. but occasionally, my ViewController miss the tap event, and finally i found that , the tap event pass to the AppDelegate, and the closeButtonPressed method in AppDelegate is invoked!

i spent a whole day in this problem, and still don't know why. can you give me a clue? thanks a lot. following is the code, hope it can help:

the code to init and present my ViewController and View:

```
YLSRegisterStepOneViewController *step1Controller = [[YLSRegisterStepOneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
step1Controller.view = [[YLSRegisterStepOneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 720) OperType:operType];
step1Controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
step1Controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;   
[self presentViewController:step1Controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the code of the UIView:

```
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
[closeButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"button_close", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton addTarget:self.controller action:@selector(closeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self addSubview:closeButton];
```

the code of the UIViewController:

```
-(void) closeButtonPressed
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];// to dismiss self
}
```

additional: aside the UIButton, there is a UITextField. when this problem happens, if i click the UITextField, then click the UIButton, UIViewController works fine

Comment: Did you set the property `controller` in `YLSRegisterStepOneView`.

Comment: in first version, i didn't set, but the code works because of Responder Chain...then i find this problem, and try to set the controller property, but the problem remain. what confuse me most is: it doesn't happend every time, but by chance, occasionally

Comment: Can you show me how you set the property.

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to paste code in comment, so i paste them in the second answer, please see there

Comment: You can edit your question here...

Comment: i am sure that: tap event triggerd, because i implement the closeButtonPressed method in the last one responder -- AppDelegate, and the mothed is invoked. but the ViewController just miss the event

Comment: additional: aside the UIButton, there is a UITextField. when this problem happens, if i click the UITextField, then click the UIButton, UIViewController works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set controller property of `YLSRegisterStepOneView` like this:

```
YLSRegisterStepOneViewController *step1Controller = [[YLSRegisterStepOneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
YLSRegisterStepOneView *step1View = [[YLSRegisterStepOneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 720) OperType:operType];
step1Controller.view = step1View;
step1View.controller = step1Controller;
```

You add the button in `YLSRegisterStepOneView`'s `initWithFrame:` method, don't you?

So `[closeButton addTarget:self.controller action:@selector(closeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` self.controller here is still nil.

`step1View.controller = step1Controller;` is called after `[closeButton addTarget:self.controller action:@selector(closeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

updated:
You say the responder chain confuses you, I think the problem is that you assign view controller's view property like this `step1Controller.view = step1View;` which is not recommended. If you want to use your custom view as viewcontroller's view, do this:

Override `loadView` method in viewcontroller.
You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    YLSRegisterStepOneView *step1View = [[YLSRegisterStepOneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 720) OperType:operType];
    self.view = step1View ;
}
```

Comment: oh yes! what stupid i am. i think it make sense, i will try what you say. however i still confuse why this happen occasionally, i think even the target is nil, the responder chain mechanism should do something..., but at least, maybe you point the way to solve this problem

Comment: yes, now i set controller property when i init the UIView, and it works fine. thank you friend. however the responder chain still confuse me, i will follow it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are setting the controller property of the custom view which you are passing here:

```
[closeButton addTarget:*self.controller* action:@selector(closeButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I think if you create/set the controller property in your view it would solve the problem (unless you are already doing it but code is not here).

Comment: hi, thank you for reply. actually i have try what you say, but it doesn't work. in fact, when i set the controller property, the ViewController still miss the event occasionally. what confused me is: this happend occasionally, not every time